# Boot from USB does not work although it is bootable

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, uefi, tablet, usb-boot

I want to install Linux on my Windows 10 tablet ([ChiliGREEN](http://www.chiligreen.com/shop/configurator.asp?typ=214&serie=587&id=15431&shopid=4642201513&extid=4001247_176179_54366382) E-Board MW065, 1 GB RAM, 8 inch display), so I created 2 bootable USB flash drives, one with Lubuntu 64-bit and one with Zorin OS Lite 32-bit.

I can boot from them on a PC, but when I try to boot from them on my tablet, it does not work. When I select "Boot Override" in the UEFI and select the USB, the display becomes dark for half a second and then shows the boot menu again (see [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Idmy5nJGBsdU4_yTzVkTEVoje47BKCNw/view?usp=sharing)). A change in the boot priority order does not change anything as well.

I hope you can help me!

EDIT:
"Legacy boot" is enabled and "Secure boot" is disabled.

Comment: Maybe "secure boot" is enabled?

Comment: Oh thanks for reminding me, I forgot to mention that.

IMPORTANT: 
"Legacy boot" is enabled and "Secure boot" is disabled.

Comment: I would make a step back and create a bootable Windows 10 installer USB stick just to test if USB boot works at all.

Comment: @Robert I created a bootable Windows 10 installer USB stick using the Microsoft-tool and tried to boot from it. It did not work, so I added a certain "bootia32.efi" file in the /boot/efi/ folder. Then it partly worked: When I boot from the USB stick on the tablet, the grub menu appears.

Comment: Does nobody have an idea?